# what are the key resources need to specify in the pv and pvc for storing the files which was uploaded in the website?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

i need to store the uploaded files from the website. i configured pv and pvc for that. but i was unable to store the files to the specified path in the pv. and then i am using kubernetes version 1.27. suggest me the pv and pvc configuration for the kubernetes v1.27 to store the uploaded files on the website. here are my pv and pvc [pv configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgqaW.png) [pvc configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3MP1.png)

suggest me some new pv and pvc configuration to store the uploaded files in the specified path in pv.i have tried all the methods but none of them was not working

Comment: You probably shouldn't create either of these resources at all.  If you _need_ a stateful workload like this, creating it as a StatefulSet and letting that manage the storage is the best approach; but better still would be to store the content somewhere remote and use a Deployment without any sort of persistence for your main application.  It looks like you've included a couple of the image files you want to store; what Kubernetes configuration have you written, and what more specific problems have you run into?